# Why we call always base class method like base.OnInit()

Tags: asp.net

I am new in asp .net.I am not able to undestand why we call base class method when we 
override methods/events.Like automatically visual studio will put base.OnInit() if you are overriding OnInit.

```
  protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

same is the case of Finalize. In derived we call base.Finalize()

Is there any need of calling these base class methods ?

Thanks

Ritu

Answer (score 7):

Yes, if you don't put it in, then any code in the base OnInit method will not run, and you may miss something important...

Generally, you will override these methods when you want to do something *additional*.  If you want to completely change them, then don't call the base method.

Comment: One thing to be aware of, especially in the ASP.net page/control life cycle is that a lot of the time, any event handlers will be called in the base.OnXXXX method, removing the call to the base.OnXXXX can often prevent these from firing....

Comment: Richard Thanks for your answer can you please give me any code example how event handler will be effected if I will not put base.XXXX Like Paddy also saying I can miss something important .please explain what I will miss if I am not going to call base.XXX Thanks in advance Ritu Thanks

Comment: @Ritu - Without knowing exactly what you're doing, it's hard to provide an example.  Why don't you try it with some sample code?

Comment: @Paddy: When overriding a base method, in what order do we have to call the base? After or before our codes?

Comment: @Forgiver - It depends on what your code is doing... If it's doing something that the base init will depend on, then do it first, otherwise, probably afterwards...  But it really depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call base version of the method in derived or sub class when the method of base class is over-ridden in the sub-class and you want to execute the base class version of the method in the sub-class.